# R Removing attached numbers

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I'm cleaning some data and there are cells throughout that have footnote numbers in them that I want to get rid of. There are cells in the row names that use numbers, too, so I can't just extract words.

```
data <- data.frame(Characteristic =  c('Race3 and Origin', 'Sex','Age 18 to
45', 'Age 55 and older'), Number =  c(40, 50, 60, 1), Margin4 = c(12, 22, 5,
1))

data$Characteristic <- as.character(data$Characteristic)
```

I'd tried a number of patterns, most recently:

```
df$Characteristic <- str_extract_all(df$Characteristic, "([:alpha:]* 
[:space:]?\\d{2,})|([:alpha:]*)|[:space:]")
```

but that leaves me with a list of `<chr [2]>`

doing str_extract (without all) gives me back just the first word.

What am I missing?

Comment: If you want to remove, why use `str_extract_all`? Your pattern does not help understand what issue you are having.

Comment: What is the expected output

Comment: I'm using str_extract/_all to keep only the words, spaces, and unattached numbers (leaving numbers attached to words, but keeping the words, out of the resulting column).

Comment: Try to remove the digits glued to letters, `data$Characteristic <- str_replace_all(data$Characteristic, "(?<=\\p{L})\\d+", "")`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks Wiktor, this worked, too.

Comment: @ajbentley I posted both base R and stringr solutions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may remove all digits glued to letters (at the end of the word) using

```
data$Characteristic <- gsub("(?<=\\p{L})\\d+\\b", "", data$Characteristic, perl=TRUE)
```

Or

```
library(stringr)
data$Characteristic <- str_replace_all(data$Characteristic, "(?<=\\p{L})\\d+\\b", "")
```

The pattern matches

- `(?<=\\p{L})` - any position immediately preceded with a letter
- `\\d+` - 1 or more digits
- `\\b` - a word boundary.

#### See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/FgELmO/2)

Answer (score 1):

Is this something you want?

```
sub("([a-zA-Z]*)[0-9]*(\\s*\\s)","\\1\\2"  , data$C)

[1] "Race and Origin"  "Sex"              "Age 18 to\n45"    "Age 55 and older"
```